# Math Day's Hours Minutes Seconds

Tags: c#, math, time, string-formatting

This question is asked multiple time's, but i can't get it working...

I'm working on an program that calculates the distance between two points, and the calculates the time an unit walks about it...

This is the simplefied version of what i need to do:

```
x = 24 
y = 23

Root of (24² + 23²) = 33.24 fields

33.24 x 30 = 997,2 minuts

997,2/60 = 16,62 hours
16: (60*0.62) = 16:37,2   
16:37: (60*0,2) = 16:37:12
```

So i've got this piece of code in C#, but it isn't working:

```
first_town = "35|629";
second_town = "59|606";
snelheidUnit = 30;

string[] firstTownSplit = first_town.Split('|');
string[] secondTownSplit = second_town.Split('|');
int firstTownPart1 = Convert.ToInt32(firstTownSplit[0]);
int firstTownPart2 = Convert.ToInt32(firstTownSplit[1]);
int secondTownPart1 = Convert.ToInt32(secondTownSplit[0]);
int secondTownPart2 = Convert.ToInt32(secondTownSplit[1]);

int verschilX = firstTownPart1 - secondTownPart1;
int verschilY = firstTownPart2 - secondTownPart2;

double aantalVelden = Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow(verschilX, 2) + Math.Pow(verschilY,2)));       // Fields
double aantalMinuten = aantalVelden * snelheidUnit;             // Minuts
double aantalUren = aantalMinuten / 60;                 // Hours

TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromHours(aantalUren);
string FinalTime = string.Format("{0:D2}d:{1:D2}h:{2:D2}m:{3:D2}s:{4:D3}ms", time.Days, time.Hours, time.Minutes, time.Seconds, time.Milliseconds);
```

The expected output should be: 00d:16h:37m:12s:772ms

But is: 00d:16h:37m:14s:772ms

The difrnce is 2 seconds. What is the bottleneck? Why is there 2 seconds difrnce between the expected output and the real output?

Comment: so what are you getting? and which part is not working right?

Comment: @artsylar, well first off all... it didn't work at all. I only get some seconds. But somehow it is working. But the output is diffrent. I will update the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Root of (24² + 23²) = 33.24 fields

The square root of `1105` isn't *exactly* `33.24`; you only get `33.24` if you round the square root. So compare your problem description:

> ```
> 33.24 x 30 = 997,2 minuts
>
> 997,2/60 = 16,62 hours
> 16: (60*0.62) = 16:37,2   
> 16:37: (60*0,2) = 16:37:12
> ```

against what happens with a more precise value for the square root:

> ```
> 33.241540277189322804630581542105 * 30 = 997.24620831567968413891744626316 minutes
> less 16 hours (960 minutes) leaves 37.246208315679684138917446263157 minutes
> less 37 minutes leaves 0.246208315679684138917446263157 minutes
> which gives 14.772498940781048335046775789394 seconds
> ```

which is about 2 seconds different from what you are getting

If you want to reproduce your original calculation, you need to do something after

```
double aantalVelden = Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow(verschilX, 2) + Math.Pow(verschilY,2)));       // Fields
```

to **round** that in the same way as your original; for example,

```
aantalVelden  = Math.Round(aantalVelden, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems it works like it should. There are just small differences in decimal values resulting in few seconds diff in the end from your expected result. Here is code that i have used:

```
        double verschilX = 24;
        double verschilY = 23;
        double snelheidUnit = 30;

        double aantalVelden = Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow(verschilX, 2) + Math.Pow(verschilY, 2)));       // Fields 
        double aantalMinuten = aantalVelden * snelheidUnit;             // Minuts 
        double aantalUren = aantalMinuten / 60;                 // Hours 

        TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromHours(aantalUren);
        string FinalTime = string.Format("{0:D2}d:{1:D2}h:{2:D2}m:{3:D2}s:{4:D3}ms", time.Days, time.Hours, time.Minutes, time.Seconds, time.Milliseconds);
```

Comment: But how could i make it exact the same then?

Comment: You should round middle results before procesing to next step. But I think its better (more accurate) like it is now, so I would keep it this way.

Comment: So if i understand you right, there isn't an way to make it exact the right answer?!?

Comment: Code like it is now it will return you the most exact result as possible with given variable types. Consider this: lets say we have to multipy 10.3445x5.1233, the exact result will be 52.997976... But if you round this result to 2 decimal places you will end up with 53.00. While you were preforming manual calculation you were rounding with less decimals then your code did and this is the reason for few seconds diff in the end.

Comment: Alright, i understand that. I've readed that if i use this: `Math.Floor(123456.646 * 100) / 100` the result will then `123456.64`  But where does i have to set it then? so it will be rounded the way i want it?

Comment: Alright, somehow this wass the answer: aantalVelden  = Math.Round(aantalVelden, 2); mentiod by AakashM

Comment: I suggest you to check (round) line by line and compare with expected manual result. This way you will see what line result needs to be rounded and how much.

Comment: Thanks for the help, so you deserved an upvote. But the bottlneck was that the aantalVelden was to precise. But thank you verry much for thinking with us :D

Answer (score 0):

I took your code, which didnt compile and made

```
        double verschilY = 24;
        double verschilX = 23;
        double aantalVelden = Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow(verschilX, 2) + Math.Pow(verschilY, 2)));       // Fields 
        double aantalMinuten = aantalVelden * 30;             // Minuts 
        double aantalUren = aantalMinuten / 60;                 // Hours 
        TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromHours(aantalUren); 
        string FinalTime = string.Format("{0:D2}d:{1:D2}h:{2:D2}m:{3:D2}s:{4:D3}ms", time.Days, time.Hours, time.Minutes, time.Seconds, time.Milliseconds);
        Console.WriteLine(FinalTime);
```

And it came back with the right answer.

Comment: But why get i 2 seconds difrnce then?

Comment: Probably because you truncated decimals in your initial calculations

Comment: Nope, as you can see in the updated code, am i using int for the coords, and the difrnce (wich is always an rounded number), and am i using doubles for the rest of the code, so no rounding should be done....

Comment: No, I meant in your jotted simplified notes you truncated

Comment: Alright, i understand that. I've readed that if i use this: `Math.Floor(123456.646 * 100) / 100` the result will then `123456.64`  But where does i have to set it then? so it will be rounded the way i want it?

Comment: Surely you want the right answer which is 14s, not the rounded wrong answer of 12s

Comment: i know it for sure. But the answer is given. i had to add this line of code: aantalVelden  = Math.Round(aantalVelden, 2);